# I couldn' t start app in ionic --v2

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

I couldn't start an ionic app . npm and node is at the latest version. but couldn't make it.. here is the shot, if you help me i will be honoured.

[image]

Comment: Looks like you made a typo somewhere: instead of `npm install` there is a `npminstall` (without a space). Look for it and check if this helps

Comment: i install may be 10 times ionic info seems fine also

Comment: Have you tried running the suggested command for installing Cordova CLI? (it's contained in the screenshot)

Comment: yeah i just installed it didnt work too. thank you..

Comment: Has the error changed or is it the same?

Comment: same for 10 days :(

Comment: I could try to reproduce your error at home, but I won't be there for next ~9 hours. If you could provide me information, whether your application is made out of some tmplate or not, it would be great. Providing me with your project and source code packed - even better.